Do we have to tell the instance at aws EC2 to move to next lifecycle state explictly?
I am doing autoscaling for updating ami images
what i am doing is

double the instances(new will have new instances have new ami)
new instances are up and running but i see that their lifecycle status is pening:wait(as per the documentation its default timeout is 1 hours and after it goes automatically to next step)

How would i move to next state, without waiting for default timeout once my applications are deployed to the new instances
and i want to go to the next step, without waiting for timeout, how would aws instance know that the software/applications deployment is done do i have to mannulay tell it then how
Write now i am just waiting for one hour(timeout)

Pending just means the operating system is booting up. It should automatically go to Running after a few minutes. If it isn't going into Running state automatically, and fairly quickly, then there is something wrong with your AMI.

Are you specifically using Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling lifecycle hooks - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling? If not, then lifecycle states do not apply. If you are using lifecycle hooks, then the instances will need to signal their readiness back to Auto Scaling.

@JohnRotenstein yeah its solved i am using a hook for lifecycle now
